# Solve inviscid Burgers' equation with shock

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

> Consider the initial value problem for the Burgers' equation:
>   \begin{equation}
> \begin{cases}u_t+uu_x=0\\u(x,0)=\phi(x)\end{cases}
> \end{equation}
>   where
>   $$\phi(x)=
> \begin{cases}
> 2 & \text{if }x\leq0\\
> 2-x & \text{if }0\leq x\leq2\\
> 0 &  \text{if }x \geq 2.
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   Find $u(x,t)$ for all $t > 0$.
>
> Show that the entropy condition is satisfied along the shock curve.

Could someone help me out with this problem.
 I know that the method of characteristics gives $u=\phi(x-ut)$:
$$
u(x,t) = \left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
&2 &&\text{if}\quad x\leq 2t\\
&\tfrac{2-x}{1-t} &&\text{if}\quad 2t\leq x \leq 2\\
&0 &&\text{if}\quad x\geq 2
\end{aligned}\right.
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution obtained with the method of characteristics looks correct. One can observe that this solution is only valid for $t< 1$. At $t=1$, all characteristic curves with initial data in $0\leq x\leq 2$ intersect at the abscissa $x=2$. Thus, the method of characteristics breaks down ($t=1$ is called the *breaking time*). A shock wave is generated with data $u_L=2$ on the left and $u_R=0$ on the right. According to the Rankine-Hugoniot condition, the shock speed is $s=\frac{1}{2}(0+2)=1$. Since $u_L>s>u_R$, the Lax entropy condition is satisfied. Finally, the entropy solution for $t>1$ reads
$$
u(x,t) = \left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
&2 & &\text{if}\quad x<1+t\\
&0 & &\text{if}\quad x>1+t
\end{aligned}\right.
$$